# fatal error : occi.h no such file or directory in centos6.6

Tags: c++, linux

i've using VMWARE 12, centos6.6(virtual machine1) and oracle11gr2 server in 2nd os - centos6.6 (virtual machine 2). i'm trying to connect C++ in client machine and oracle11gr2 in server.  problem is that in my cpp code

```
enter code here

 #include <iostream>
 #include <occi.h> // here "oracle/11.2/client/occi.h" shows by editor codeBlocks but can not detects this.

  using namespace std;

int main(){

 oracle::occi::Environment* environment;
 oracle::occi::Connection *con;
 oracle::occi::Statement* stmt;
 oracle::occi::ResultSet* res;

 try{

     environment = oracle::occi::Environment::createEnvironment(oracle::occi::Environment::DEFAULT);
     con = environment->createConnection("rahul", "rahul", "ora11gr2");

     stmt = con->createStatement("select * from example");
     res = stmt->executeQuery();

     while (res->next())
         std::cout<<res->getInt(1)<<"  "<<res->getString(2)<<std::endl;

     stmt->closeResultSet(res);
     con->terminateStatement(stmt);
     environment->terminateConnection(con);

 }catch(oracle::occi::SQLException &e){
     std::cout<<e.what();
 }
 return 0;
 }
```

and error is given by compiler : /opt/projects/codeblock projects/c++ oracle/main.cpp|2|fatal error: occi.h: No such file or directory|

my env are :-

```
   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client/lib:/opt/oracle/instantclient_11_2:/opt/Qt5.3.2/5.3/Src/qtbase/lib:

 $LD_LIBRARY_PATHexport 

PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client/bin:/opt/oracle/instantclient_11_2: /opt/Qt5.3.2/5.3/gcc/bin:/sbin:$PATH
 export TNS_ADMIN=/opt/oracle/instantclient_11_2


export INCLUDEPATH=/opt/Qt5.3.2/5.3/gcc/include/QtPlatformSupport/5.3.2/QtPlatformSupport/private:/#usr/include/oracle/11.2/client:/opt/Qt5.3.2/5.3/gcc/include:$INCLUDEPATH
```

and

```
  export OCI_LIB_DIR=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client/libexport
  OCI_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/oracle/11.2/clientexport 
  OCI_VERSION=11
  export OCI_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/oracle/11.2/client 
  ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client
```

there is one problem is that on command prompt, when run in shell error  is 
"# source /etc/bashrc" (enter)
error is:- ": command not found"

Comment: I don't see sd/include in your include path.

Comment: @ Oleksandr Kravchuk  : what is sd in sd/include

Comment: sorry, I've meant sdk/include

Comment: for this please tell me what should be sdk/include